# .Net Maui How to add Input Field Description

Tags: maui

I want to create a simple input field in .Net Maui as follows:

[image]

Could you please advise how to this.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

use a *Layout* like a `HorizontalStackLayout` or a `Grid` to create a composite control

```
<HorizontalStackLayout>
    <Label Text="Name" />
    <Entry />
</HorizontalStackLayout>
```